# Associativity of cup product in Homology

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, functors

Studying Algebraic Topology from [Tom Dieck](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/diecktop.pdf) I came across [cup product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup_product). I was trying to verify whether there were a way to prove associativity without using the direct formula of cup, just exploit the naturality of cap product thanks to its definition on chain level (depending on [Eilenberg-Zilber Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Zilber_theorem) for example using the [Alexander-Whitney map](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Alexander-Whitney+map)).

In particular in my notes there's the following diagram, but I don't know what should suggest me

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 X  & \overset{\triangle}{\rightarrow} & X \times X & \overset{1 \times \triangle}{\rightarrow} X \times(X \times X) \\\
& & \downarrow{\triangle \times 1} & \\\
 &  & (X \times X) \times X
\end{array}$$

Where $\triangle$ is the diagonal map and $1$ is the identity.

Any help or answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out Davis and Kirk, lecture notes in algebraic topology, chapter 3, theorem 3.13.